How to save numpy.ndarray in static or thread local variable in python extension written in Rust with PyO3?
I am building a simple python extension to process numpy.ndarray objects using rust-numpy crate. I want to save numpy.ndarray objects in static or thread local variables for later process:
use std::cell::RefCell;
use numpy::PyReadwriteArray1;
use pyo3::{Bound, pymodule, PyResult, types::PyModule};

thread_local! {
    static ARRAYS: RefCell<Vec::<PyReadwriteArray1<i32>>> = RefCell::new(Vec::<PyReadwriteArray1<i32>>::new());
}

#[pymodule]
fn rust_ext<'py>(m: &Bound<'py, PyModule>) -> PyResult<()> {
    #[pyfn(m)]
    fn register_array(mut x: PyReadwriteArray1<i32>) {
        x.as_array_mut()[0] = 100;
        ARRAYS.with_borrow_mut(|v| v.push(x));
    }

    Ok(())
}

But I got lifetime compile error:
static ARRAYS: RefCell<Vec::<PyReadwriteArray1<i32>>> = RefCell::new(Vec::<PyReadwriteArray1<i32>>::new());
  |                                                   ^ expected named lifetime parameter

So is it possible to save python objects in extension written in Rust? If so, how to fix 'py lifetime issue?

To hold a Python value outside of the GIL, you need it wrapped in a Py. You can get one from PyReadwriteArray1 using .as_unbound().clone() and you would use simply need to have the GIL to "unlock" it later. However, that gives you a PyArray since PyReadwriteArray1 is only a light wrapper around one. If that works, then great! If not then I'm not sure what can be done.

@kmdreko @kmdreko Thank you! It works! Now I can save ndarray to thread local variable of type RefCell<Vec::<Py<PyArray<i32, Ix1>>>>. In process function, I find that I have to use Python::with_gil(|py| {}) and bind every PyArray object to this py to get a mutable slice to modify items. Do you think this is a good way?

@kmdreko after clear the thread local Vec, I find ndarray in Python environment has right reference count. So is it necessery to use Python::with_gil(|py| {}) and bind operation to access inner object of Py<T>, just like this: item.bind(py).readwrite().as_slice_mut().unwrap()? Thank you.

That is right! I've written this up and added detail in my answer.

Are you sure you really want a thread local?

@ChayimFriedman I just need somewhere to store all ndarrays for later process in batch. I provide a function to register ndarray object. I think local thread or global static variable are both ok because there is only one thread. Do you have any better suggestions?

A static with GILOnceCell?

@ChayimFriedman I'm just starting to use PyO3. This seems to be a feasible way, and I will try it.

To hold a Python value outside of the GIL, you need it wrapped in a Py. You can get one from PyReadwriteArray1 using .as_unbound() which will yield a Py<PyArray1>. So your thread local would look like this:
thread_local! {
    static ARRAYS: RefCell<Vec<Py<PyArray1<i32>>>> = RefCell::new(Vec::new());
}

let py = x.py();
let arr = x.as_unbound().clone_ref(py);
ARRAYS.with_borrow_mut(|v| v.push(arr));

To get the value back from the Py, you need to "unlock" it with a Python<'_> token indicating you have the GIL. You will get this normally in your functions either directly or accessible by .py() on an existing parameter. You'll likely want to get it as a Bound by using .bind(). See the Py documentation for other options.
Beyond that, you can get the PyArray1 as a PyReadwriteArray1 by using .readwrite() or .try_readwrite() via PyReadwriteArray1:
// just getting the first one as a demonstration
let arr = ARRAYS.with_borrow(|v| v[0].bind(py).clone());
let x = arr.readwrite();

// do whatever with the PyReadwriteArray1

